# Python global object variable

Tags: class, object, python-2.7, pyqt

I want to make use on an object that has been instantinated inside of a class from a standalone module. I am trying to do this by makeing the object reference global. I think I want to make use of the current object and not create a new one.

Assume I have this code in a module file

```
import moduleFile
class A():
    def checkAdmin(self):
        global adminMenu
        adminMenu = SRMadminMenu()

class SRMadminMenu()
    def createAdminMenu(self):
        pass
        ####Put code to create menu here####

    def createSubMenu(self,MenuText):
        pass
        ####Create a submenu with MenuText####
```

In moduleFile.py I have this code

```
def moduleFile_Admin_Menu():
    global adminMenu
    adminMenu.createSubMenu("Module Administration")
```

the code in moduleFile.py gives me the following error.

```
NameError: global name 'adminMenu' is not defined
```

Comment: should `Import` not be `import` ?, also where is `adminMenu` declared?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the typo. adminMenu in declared in checkAdmin() in the A class.

Comment: you are marking a global as `global adminMenu`. You need to declare it somewhere. Example, `adminMenu=None` or something. example - just below `import moduleFile`

Comment: OK, I have declared adminMenu=None but I still get the same error when I import moduleFile and call moduleFile_Admin_Menu() - NameError: global name 'adminMenu' is not defined

Comment: One thing- you might have to declare in `moduleFile.py` and not the other way round

Comment: I tried that, but it just sets the value of adminMenu to None and I then have no reference to the object I instantinated in A()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29807/discussion-between-prestondocks-and-karthikr)

Answer (score 15):

You must declare global variable outside from class.

```
## Code file something.py
import moduleFile

adminMenu = None

class A():
    def checkAdmin(self):
        global adminMenu
        adminMenu = SRMadminMenu()
```

then moduleFile.py,

```
from something import adminMenu

def moduleFile_Admin_Menu():
    global adminMenu
    adminMenu.createSubMenu("Module Administration")
```

Note: If you will not change adminMenu variable, you don't have to write `global adminMenu`

One clarification for that last sentence.  If you need access the adminMenu variable from within a separate function outside the class (for example, a callback function), then even if you are NOT going to change the variable, you will still need to declare the variable as global.  Otherwise, the function will think the variable is local and an access will result in a read-before-assignment error.