# Instantiating a global object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some Python code similar to the following:

```
def a():
    x.b()

def c():
   x = create_x()
   a()
```

Here, `x` is an object, so in `c()`, I want to create `x`, and then run function `a()`. I want `x` to be global, rather than having to pass it as an argument to `a()`. But if I try to run the above code, it will tell me that the `x` in `a()` doesn't refer to anything.

So what is the standard solution to this? One idea is to define `x` globally and set it to 0:

```
x = 0

def a():
    global x
    x.b()

def c():
   global x
   x = create_x()
   a()
```

But this seems a little strange, because it is suggesting that `x` is an integer, whereas actually it is an object.

In C++ I would usually solve this by creating a pointer to `x`, setting this to 0, and then setting the pointer to the memory created by the new object `x`. But what's the best solution in Python?

Comment: Use `None` instead of `0`?

Comment: Don't set `x` at all initially…? It will be created by running `c`. You don't have to declare it outside the function, `global` already does that.

Comment: See if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511321/python-global-object-variable

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Making the variable global in the function it is initiated.

Problem with this code is that b has to be called before a.

```
def a():
    print(x)

def b():
    global x 
    x = 1
    a()

b()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if answering the question, but it looks like you need to call `global x` only inside the `c()` function.

```
class XClass:
    def b(self):
        print 'hello world'

def create_x():
    return XClass()

def a():
    x.b()

def c():
    global x
    x = create_x()
    a()

c() # hello world
a() # hello world
```

Maybe it less confusing if you create the `x` variable inside the `create_x()` method:

```
class XClass:
    def b(self):
        print 'hello world'

def create_x():
    global x
    x = XClass()

def a():
    x.b()

def c():
    create_x()
    a()

c() # hello world
a() # hello world
x.b() # hello world
```